# filling of a ballon and gas law

Tags: everyday-chemistry

When we fill a balloon with gas the pressure and volume inside it increases. Will this not go against the gas law as  pressure and temperature are inversely proportional to each other.

Comment: The said law is applicable if we have constant amount of gas.

Comment: @Ivan You mean the OP's *interpretation* of the law? Glorfindel's answer seems plausible, yet he doesn't "pin-down" one of the parameters in the Ideal gas law. [Side note: Why on earth do you keep away from The Periodic Table? It'll be interesting to have you there ;) ]

Comment: @paracetamol I mean Boyle's law, not the full PV=nRT thing. What is The Periodic Table?

Answer (score 3):

No. The [Ideal gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law) states that

$$PV = nRT$$

You're right that the left hand side (pressure times volume) increases, but so does $n$, the amount of substance of gas. So the ideal gas law is still satisfied.